# How to apply explicit API mode to all modules except the app module?

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, groovy, kotlin-gradle-plugin

I like to apply the [explicit API mode](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/whatsnew14.html#explicit-api-mode-for-library-authors) to all modules in [this Android project](https://github.com/EventFahrplan/EventFahrplan) **except** to the `app` module. This works fine by adding the following configuration to the *build.gradle* file of each module.

```
// build.gradle of a module

kotlin {    
    explicitApi() 
}
```

I like to however avoid the **repetitive** declaration. Therefore, I aim to configure it once it the *build.gradle* file in the **project root**. I tried the following:

```
// build.gradle in project root

allprojects {
    apply plugin: "kotlin"
    kotlin {
        if (project.name != "app") {
            explicitApi()
        }
    }
}
```

This collides with the plugin definition in the modules:

> Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.PluginApplicationException: Failed to apply plugin 'kotlin-android'.
> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot add extension with name 'kotlin', as there is an extension already registered with that name.
> Caused by: com.android.build.gradle.internal.BadPluginException: The 'java' plugin has been applied, but it is not compatible with the Android plugins.

## Related

- [Gradle Multi Module Project: Apply module dependency to all subprojects except for itself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59443464/gradle-multi-module-project-apply-module-dependency-to-all-subprojects-except-f)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `build.gradle` applies the Kotlin plugin to subprojects before they apply the Android plugin, which doesn't work - it needs to be the other way around.

Try postponing the action until after the project is evaluated, for example

```
gradle.afterProject { project ->
    if (project.name == "app") return
    project.extensions.findByName("kotlin")?.explicitApi()
}
```

Comment: Thank you. If I understand correctly, this does the same as `Gradle#projectsEvaluated(Closure)` with the advantage that `Gradle#afterProject(Closure)` provides access to the `project` parameter.

Comment: @JJD `projectsEvaluated` invokes its closure once after all projects are evaluated. `afterProject` invokes its closure immediately after each project is evaluated. `projectsEvaluated { allprojects { ... } }` would be *similar* to `afterProject {... }` but it is not quite the same thing.